# How to apply a png texture to a glTF model with React-three/fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber, tsx

I'm trying to apply a texture map that is a png to a glTF model I have. I just can't figure out how.
Currently, I can import the glTF model properly by doing:

```
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
const Scene = () => {
const gltf = useGLTF('*path*');
    return (
        <>
            <primitive object={gltf.scene} />
        </>
    );
};
```

I can also get a sphere of the png by doing:

```
import { useTexture } from "@react-three/drei";
const Scene = () => {
    const texture = useTexture('*path*');
    return (
        <>
            <mesh>
                <sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 32, 32]} />
                <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" map={texture} />
            </mesh>
        </>
    );
};
```

How do I get the texture to be applied to the model? I tried to replace the `<sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 32, 32]} />` with `<primitive object={gltf.scene} />` but that doesn't work. I am using TSX instead of JSX.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easy workaround. Instead of importing the GLTF and the animation files separately, I combined them into a single GLB file. I used this website to combine the file. https://sbtron.github.io/makeglb/